# How to clear static method status during junit test

Tags: android, junit, robolectric

The test function `test_init_1()` succeed, but `test_init_2()` fails 
That is because `MyService` has been already initialized.

```
@RunWith(RobolectricTestRunner::class)
class TrackingServiceInitTest {
    @Test
    fun test_init_1() {
        val result = MyService.init(context, id1) 
        assertTrue(result)  // result = `true`
    }

    @Test
    fun test_init_2() {
        val result = MyService.init(context, id2) 
        assertTrue(result)  // AlreadyInitialized Exception has thrown!
    }

    @After
    fun tearDown() {
        // what should I do here to clear MyService's state?
    }
}
```

MyService looks like:

```
public class MyService {
    public static synchronized boolean init(Context context) {
        if (sharedInstance != null) {
            Log.d(TAG, "Already initialized!");
            throw new AlreadyInitialized();
        }

        // initializing.. 
        sharedInstance = new CoreService();
        return true
    }
}
```

How can I clear such status?

Answer (score 1):

The right solution would be adding a static method to `MyService` marked with `@VisibleForTesting` which releases `sharedInstance`:

```java
public class MyService {
    public static synchronized boolean init(Context context) {
        if (sharedInstance != null) {
            Log.d(TAG, "Already initialized!");
            throw new AlreadyInitialized();
        }

        // initializing..
        sharedInstance = new CoreService();
        return true;
    }

    @VisibleForTesting
    public static void destroy() {
        sharedInstance = null;
    } 
}
```

And then in your `tearDown` you can call `MyService.destroy()`.

Comment: It looks like it is working, but I'd rather find other way like divide them into individual classes